# How to hide a div while scrolling in Ionic?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am building an application using Ionic (version 1) and would like to hide a div from the controller when the user is scrolling. I am stuck and don't know where to start.

This is my code:

```
  <body ng-app="starter" style="padding-top:150px;">

     <div  ng-controller="AppCtrl" id="header" >
        <div class="bar-aaa">
            <div class="myLogo">
                <img src="img/images/logo.png" style="display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;height:50px;margin-top:10px;margin-bottom:30px;" alt=""/>
            </div>

            <div class="row" style="padding-bottom: 0px;">
                <div class="col col-33" style="border-bottom: 2px solid {{oneLine}};margin-bottom: 0;height: 59px;"><a href="javascript:;" ui-sref="app.dashboard" style="display: block;padding: 19px 0px 37px;margin-top: -19px;"><img src="{{one}}" style="display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" alt=""/></a></div>
                <div class="col col-33" style="border-bottom: 2px solid {{twoLine}};margin-bottom: 0;height: 59px;"><a href="javascript:;" ng-click="allCoupons();" on-swipe-left="allCoupons();" style="display: block;padding: 19px 0px 37px;margin-top: -19px;"><img src="{{two}}" style="height:17px;display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" alt=""/></a></div>
                <div class="col col-33" style="border-bottom: 2px solid {{threeLine}};margin-bottom: 0;height: 59px;"><a href="javascript:;"  ui-sref="app.settings" style="display: block;padding: 19px 0px 37px;margin-top: -19px;"><img src="{{three}}" style="height:17px;display: block;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;" alt=""/></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>
     </div>
     <span ng-show="loading" style="position: absolute;z-index: 99999;margin-left:-75px;top:150px;left:50%;right:50%;background:rgba(0,0,0,0.5);text-align:center;padding:15px;width:150px;" >
        <div>
            <ion-spinner icon="spiral"></ion-spinner>
            <h5 style="color:#fff;">Processing...</h5>
        </div>

     </span>

    <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>


  </body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question does not explain which `<div>` you are trying to hide and what code you have tried to use already, but can you assign a function to the `on-scroll` directive of the `ion-content` and do whatever you want to do in that function. So like this:

```
<ion-content on-scroll="scrollFunction()">
```

And then in your controller add a function called `scrollFunction` or preferably something more descriptive.

```
$scope.getScrollPosition = function() {
  // Here you can do whatever you want when someone is scrolling.
}
```

You could for example update a variable in this function and assigned that variable to the `ng-show` of the `<div>` you want to show or hide.

---

To answer your other question regarding why the `getScrollPosition()` function keeps returning 0. It is a known issue, you can find similar reports [here](https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/issues/1931). I am not entirely sure why this happens, but it seems like Ionic is grabbing the scroll position of a different view causing it to stay 0. You can solve this by assigning a `delegate-handler` to your `<ion-content>`, which basically gives you an unique identifier to work with. It would look something like this:

```
<ion-content delegate-handle="scrollHandler" on-scroll="getScrollPosition()">
```

And then in your controller, instead of doing the following:

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top;
```

You need to do this:

```
$ionicScrollDelegate.$getByHandle("scrollHandler").getScrollPosition().top;
```

That should solve the issues you are experiencing.

Comment: thanks, but in getScrollPosition function i am using $ionicScrollDelegate.getScrollPosition().top but it always give 0 how to resolve it ?

Comment: Could be that Ionic is grabbing the wrong scroll view, you can make sure that this happens by assigning a `delegate-handle` and using that to get the scroll position. I'll add an example to the answer above.